# jQuery selector: which combination of jQuery selectors should I use to change the text between span tags

Tags: jquery, ajax, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <img id='1' class='promote' src='/images/plus.png' />
    <span>0</span>
    <img id='1' class='demote' src='/images/minus.png' />
  </td>
  <td>
    <img id='2' class='promote' src='/images/plus.png' />
    <span>0</span>
    <img id='2' class='demote' src='/images/minus.png' />
  </td>
...
</tr>
```

Next, i'm using jQuery ajax:

```
$('img.promote').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/promote/' + this.id,
    success: function(data) {
      $(???).text(data.rating);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
  });
});
$('img.demote').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
  url: '/demote/' + this.id,
  success: function(data) {
    $(???).text(data.rating);
  },
  dataType: 'json'
  });
});
```

So, which combination of jQuery selectors should I use instead of "???" to change the text between span tags? or I'm doing it wrong at all?

Comment: Are you attempting to change *all* of the spans at once? or just a particular one?

Comment: Just one, it's a part of rating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cache the span in the click handler

```
$('img.promote').click(function() {
  var $span = $(this).siblings('span');
  $.ajax({
    url: '/promote/' + this.id,
    success: function(data) {
      $span.text(data.rating);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
  });
});
```